# If statement does not work when comparing two integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'am trying to make a python sort-of calculator that allows for any amount of digits to be entered and it checks if every second "word" is an operator, but when comparing the length of the sum and the index of the "word" it is currently checking to see if it should print the output, but it does not even though the 2 integers are the same.

```
operators = ["+", "-", "/", "*"]

def doSum(sum):
    split = sum.split()
    target = len(split)
    if split[1] in operators and "=" not in "".join(split):
        for WORD in split:
            if split.index(WORD) % 2 != 0:
                if WORD in operators:
                    if int(split.index(WORD)) == int(target):
                        print(eval("".join(split)))
                    else:
                        print(target)
                        print(len(split))
                        print("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-")

doSum("1 + 2")
doSum("3 + 3")
doSum("8 - 4")
doSum("1 + 3 + 3 - 1")
```

The problem lines are lines 10 - 15.
I expected the output to be:
    3
    6
    4
    6
But I got:

```
3
3
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
3
3
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
3
3
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
7
7
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
7
7 
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
7
7
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
```

from the "else block" I use for debugging

Edit:

Thank you @chepner for providing the answer in a comment:

"Your if condition is never true because the indices of split run from 0 to len(split) - 1, and target == len(split)."

Comment: Your `if` condition is never true because the indices of `split` run from 0 to `len(split) - 1`, and `target == len(split)`.

Comment: Why is your function so complex yet does so less, if you are using `eval()` at the end why not use it before, your whole function can be condensed into 1 line`def doSum(Sum): print(eval(sum))` or are you forced to do that ?

Comment: thanks kind stanger

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import ast

>>> def doSum(sum1):
    print(ast.literal_eval(sum1))
    print('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-')


>>> doSum("1 + 2")
3
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
>>> doSum("3 + 3")
6
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
>>> doSum("8 - 4")
4
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
>>> doSum("1 + 3 + 3 - 1")
6
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
```